# Find coordinate exactly opposite to any angle based on three points

Tags: java, algorithm, java-2d

I have three points to draw two lines: `point1`, `point2`, and `point3`. `point1` is the center. I want to find out the exactly opposite coordinate at some distance from `point1`.

[image]

In Java 2D program I need to draw a bisectrix as shown on the picture above.
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Is this about how to calculate the points? Then it is not a Java but a geometry question, is it not?

Comment: Anyway...simplest way probably: Calculate a new point P4 on P1P3 with length of P1P2, be dividing and multiplying with the according magnitude. Get  half between P2 and P4. Done

Comment: can you plz explain it in more details...

Comment: Considering the question, I am slightly irritated. Up to which point are you familiar with basic geometry? Your question actually only needs basic vector orations, i.e. rescaling of distances. What is your background, which part of my previous comment you don't understand?

Comment: [Is there a uniform way to define angle bisectors using vectors?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149628/is-there-a-uniform-way-to-define-angle-bisectors-using-vectors)

Comment: another approach (less abstract and more suitable for a naive solution) - [Angle bisector theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)

Comment: Sorry, I am not good with geometry.

Comment: got simple solution here http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Analytical%20Geometry/AnalGeom_3.htm

Comment: @harshtuna Yes, "angle bisector theorem" is the one. Basically what I wrote only that I suggest making both sides equal length first, making the bisector pass half of the base of the new isosceles triangle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. It is pure geometry question.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the vector between the point P = (X,Y) and P1 =(X1,X2). Lets call it V=(V1, V2).

Lets change it direction. V' = (-V1, -V2) then add P1 the vector V'. Alternatively you may view it as a change of coordinates where P1 is the new center, change signs, and then change the coordinates back.

PS. This question is for https://math.stackexchange.com/ but seems easy.